# Special characters appear in file output

Tags: python

I have this line in a file

```
ááááááááááá06:00pá-á02:00aáááááááááá
```

I am trying to remove the special characters from it using

```
for line in open('file.txt', 'r'):
    string = line.replace('á', '')
    print(string)
```

then I run it outputting the print into a file
but in the file it is only filled with the special character `�����`

The output in the terminal looks completely normal. I have no idea what is happening.

Comment: I suggest using some tool (ie. https://pypi.org/project/chardet/, https://pypi.org/project/charset-normalizer/, or the UNIX file command) to figure what encoding your file is in, instead of ignoring the issue and resorting to hacks.

Comment: What encoding is the input file? What's your OS's default encoding? [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) will use it if no encoding is specified. Lastly, what encoding are you using to open the output file? Ideally they'd all be the same, like say UTF-8, but seems like that's not the case. If you're not sure, you can use a tool to figure it out, like @SuperStormer is saying, like the Unix `file` command.

Comment: Which OS and version of Python are you using?  It can make a huge difference.

Comment: After finding out the encoding, add `encoding='XXX'` in your `open()` function